# Refactor a multi-layered if-then

Tags: c#, if-statement

Looking for someone to proofread my logic.  I inherited a method that contains this:

```
If (a || b)
{
   doTaskOne();
}
else
{
    if (c)
    {
        doTaskOne()
    }
    doTaskTwo()
}
```

Could this be simplified like this?

```
If ((a || b) || c))
{
   doTaskOne();
}
else
{
    doTaskTwo()
}
```

Comment: It appears that it would work. Hard to say for sure unless you know what a b and c are. Also I don't think you need the extra braces.

Comment: should be work fine

Comment: Let the plethora of wrongness here be a strong reminder for "keep it simple" and "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: I think you are correct Mark

Comment: Though I agree that these changes should be done extremely carefully, I think the OP's point was exactly that - to make it as simple as possible. (Though the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" part remains true.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (a || b || c) doTaskOne();
if (!a && !b) doTaskTwo();
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: hmm... might be on to something here!

Answer (score 10):

These are not the same since in the first version if `(a || b)` is `false` and `c == true`, then both `doTaskOne()` and `doTaskTwo()` would be called, whereas your alternative only ever calls one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really simplify that logic in any cleaner way.

Comment: I've dropped my answer. BTW, I still think that if you're going to call `doTaskOne()` either if `a || b` and in a nested `if` it will be called if `a == true`, I don't see the difference of simplifying this code to `a || b || c`. It'll do `doTaskOne` if `a`, `b` or `c` are `true`.

Comment: I feel that you and others are guessing that actual code has more details that would prevent the thing of simplifying with `a || b || c`, but in terms of OP's pseudo-code... for me it's almost the same.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer The problem with your solution was the condition of the second `if`. If you had written it like ispiro it would have been correct.

Comment: @Keiwan Maybe... I see the issue, but anyway, maybe OP's scenario mightn't require `!a && !b`... Maybe it's just "do this TaskTwo whenever `c` is `true`. It's not that clear as you guess...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer There is really no guessing involved. What you are saying is not what his original code does. This is straightforward boolean logic (You could also use a truth table to get to the result of ispiro)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer -- there are ways to re-write it, but not in a cleaner, more readable way. Ispro's answer is correct, but I would write it in the original way since its more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @SledgeHammer BTW... you know that at some point readability is very subjective. I've seen spaguetti code that was readable by its author :d

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, no, it can't.  But consider an approach along these lines:

```
bool runMethodOne = false;
bool runMethodTwo = false;

if (a || b)
{
   runMethodOne = true;
}
else
{
    if (c)
    {
        runMethodOne = true;
    }
    runMethodTwo = true;
}

if(runMethodOne)
  doTaskOne();
if(runMethodTwo)
  doTaskTwo();
```

This gives you some flexibility into tweaking the boolean logic, for example

```
bool runMethodOne = (a || b);
bool runMethodTwo = !runMethodOne;
if(c)
  runMethodOne = true;
```

Or

```
bool runMethodOne = false;
bool runMethodTwo = false;

if(c)
  runMethodOne = true;

if(a||b)
  runMethodOne = true;
else
  runMethodTwo = true;
```

(This tweak may or may not be clearer depending on the actual semantics of your code; I think the original nesting is clearer)